# Counting classes & permgen using, using permstat

Tags: java, eclipse, permgen, jmap

I want to count the number of classes and the permgen space of my java code using **jmap**. However since I am running my code in ecplise , additional classes and permgen space (which belongs to ecplise ) is being shown.

I tried to run the code from my terminal but was unable to due to some dependency issues. Does someone know a way around this issue ?

Comment: Without code, preferably an SSCCE, and the exact error you get - no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896272/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-error-in-termi

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to run the code from my terminal but was unable to due to some dependency issues. Does someone know a way around this issue ?

Since your application is likely to be "of limited use" if it will only run within Eclipse, you should solve the dependency issue first, so that you *can* run your application from the command line.  That should make the permstat vs Eclipse problem a non-issue.

Comment: The reason because of which I was not able to run my code is mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896272/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-error-in-termi 

However none of the solutions/comments provided solved the error.

Comment: Not withstanding that, it is common sense to fix that problem first!

Comment: Desperate times call for desperate measures !!! My deadline is tomm & I have bee stuck with this issues for a week.