# Grails app : Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]

Tags: java, xml, grails

I am creating an application. I am getting the below error when I run the command `grails run-app` :

```
2016-05-27/12:03:46.472 [localhost-startStop-1]  ERROR context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have found similar issues on below links :

[Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530819/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-http-cxf-ap)
[Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace Error in Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896272/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-error-in-termi)

But I already have `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs` dependency and cxf jars in my classpath.

I am not getting any error when I run through intellij 14 then app is running successfully.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mad_fox : No, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including cxf-rt-frontend-jax**w**s?