# How to configure web.xml for CXF Jakson when we working with complex objects

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, cxf

I am trying to generate rest-services using Apache CXF Jackson. I have done a POC on this it's working fine also but when I try to implement the same thing on my application it is throwing some exception like below. when I comment on the related configuration code in web.xml it's working fine. below code samples.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-service-configuration.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
waited 0 ms for code server to finish
```

Here is web.xml file in my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>stockServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sathish.stocktradingdemo.server.StockTradingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>stockServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/stocktradingdemo/stockservice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--added code -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-service-configuration.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>StockTradingdemo.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is web.xml file of my POC

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-service-configuration.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my rest-service-configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
                        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.restServicePOC" />

    <jaxrs:server id="userCxfServer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="userServices"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </jaxrs:features>   
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
            <!-- <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"></bean> -->
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

I am Expecting the JSON response like

```
{"userName":"somthing","userId":101}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace \[http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530819/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-http-cxf-ap)

Comment: But that link doesn't solve my issue because I already had that cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs dependency in my pom.xml file.